# Reduce duplicate similar methods in c#

Tags: c#, oop

Has been working on a project for a while, basically it is combination of C# and Mysql as Server Side System. Due to performance issue, I am handed code ADO.NET my mysql query but I am facing a issue as I want to reduce amount of code I need to write.

Let's say

ItemService Class has methods (Below Code are just examples)

```
protected internal List<Item> Read()
    {
        List<Item> itemList = new List<Item>();
        String query = @"SELECT * FROM items";
        itemList = IRead(query);
        return itemList;
    }

protected internal Item Read(int id)
    {
        List<Item> itemList = new List<Item>();
        Item item = new Item();
        String query = String.Format(@"SELECT * FROM items WHERE id = {0}", id);
        itemList = IRead(query);
        item = itemList.FirstOrDefault();
        return item;
    }
 protected internal List<Item> Read(int startId, int limit, String orderBy = "id", String order = "ASC")
    {
        List<Item> itemList = new List<Item>();
        String query = String.Format(@"SELECT * FROM items WHERE id >= {0} ORDER BY '{1}' '{2}' LIMIT {3}", startId, orderBy, order, limit);
        itemList = IRead(query);
        return itemList;
    }
```

And OrderService Class has Very Similar Methods

```
protected internal List<Order> Read()
    {
        List<Order> orderList = new List<Order>();
        String query = @"SELECT * FROM items";
        orderList = IRead(query);
        return orderList;
    }
 protected internal Order Read(int id)
    {
        Order order = new Order();
        String query = String.Format(@"SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE id = {0}", id);
        order = IRead(query).FirstOrDefault();
        return order;
    }
```

I am thinking of using abstract class, but how can I handle different return object (except dynamic) as well as different string query inside the method. your help is much appreciated.

Comment: You could look at [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net). These queries seem simple enough and I assume aren't part of your performance problem. You should probably use an ORM and then only in the cases of performance issues, drop down to raw SQL. Most ORM's can handle you passing raw sql through them.

Comment: @Prescott Thanks for you comment, I did look through Dapper i know the performance is close to classic ado.net, however this project has been going on for a while already, it is very hard to switch (time consuming) and I still haven't fully grasp Dapper. is there any other way round except ORM ?

Comment: Dapper is not a ORM, you would simply use it instead of writing the SQL manually. Apart from this, you are probably looking for a repository pattern, and you can likely create a generic base repository, for basic CRUD operations which all entities will share. Note that [Dapper Extensions](https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions) basically gives you CRUD functionality on top of basic Dapper querying, meaning you could implement the base repo rather easily.

Comment: @Groo Thanks for your comment. Yes I agreed that Dapper will help me handle CRUD, what we has been developing is a point of sale system, and the object currently has more item than it is in database due to sharing with other logic class for order state use and etc. so there is a lot of joint object and manipulation of object in code and furthermore, database naming uses underscore while the c# code uses  lowerCamalCase, and another reason keep me from trying dapper is there is little documentation in using Dapper for C# and Mysql on internet. what is your recommendation, is it worth trying ?

Comment: Dapper just helps you parameterize queries and converts plain data readers into actual C# objects. Presumably this is what your `IRead` method does for each type separately, and Dapper allows you to abstract this step. There is probably little documentation because the usage is rather simple (i.e. it's usually just something like `conn.Query<Item>("SELECT * FROM items")` to return the list of `Item` instances). But the greater problem is that you pass a string to `IRead` and use `string.Format` to build the query, which is susceptible to SQL injection.

Comment: So, yes, I would certainly say that safer code + less lines of code is a win-win situation.

Comment: @Groo thank you. so how I can handle more attribute in code than in database, is there any tutorial ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an abstract base class that does most of the heavy lifting for you:

```
public abstract class ItemBase<T> where T : new()
{
    public abstract string table_name { get; }

    protected internal T Read(int id)
    {
        var query = $@"SELECT * FROM {table_name} WHERE id = {id}";
        //var itemList = IRead(query);
        Console.WriteLine(query); //Did this as console output for testing
        return new T(); // temList.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    protected internal List<T> Read(int startId, int limit, string orderBy = "id", string order = "ASC")
    {
        string query = $@"SELECT * FROM {table_name} WHERE id >= {startId} ORDER BY {orderBy} {order} LIMIT {limit}";
        Console.WriteLine(query); //Console output for testing
        return null;
        //return IRead(query);
    }
}
```

Then you can create the individual record classes like so:

```
public class Item : ItemBase<Item>
{
     public override string table_name => "items";
}
```

You can use it like so:

```
//Console Application:
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var i = new Item();
        i.Read(12);
        i.Read(1, 2);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is cool, although I would use a different base class name seems to be like a bad choice (e.g. something like `BaseRepository<T>` or `RepoBase<T>`, so that you can there is no "Item" in `ItemBase<Order>`)